# Can you disable menu bar transparency in Mac OS X?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

Depending on the wallpaper I select in Mac OS X 10.6, the menu bar is semi-translucent. Ironically, on black backgrounds, this looks best, as it comes out a simple, flattish gray. On any background I select which has strong colors, however, it either becomes a distraction or (to me) makes the menu bar near-unintelligible.

The simple answer is to stick with less-bold backgrounds. But that really limits my selection, and I like to change things up every now and again.

Can the transparency be removed / toned down / adjusted in OS X 10.6?

Comment: You might want to remove the images, or upload scaled down versions. Even with 10Mbit internet, it takes a while to load.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable the transparency of the menu bar:

- Open your Systems Preferences window
- Open the Desktop & Screensaver window
  under the "Personal" section
- Uncheck
  the "Translucent Menu Bar" option

[Source](http://www.technipages.com/mac-os-x-leopard-disable-transparent-menu-bar.html)

Comment: And ... I officially feel like a moron. I somehow never saw that option, but thanks a million, because it works. :)

Comment: For future reference, searches in system preferences are quite powerful: a search for "menu bar" would have brought up an auto-complete list with "Translucent menu bar" being the first item. Selecting that item highlights the Desktop & Screensaver pane. (This is in OS 10.6)

Comment: In the new Yosemite, you can find "Reduce transparency" in Accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

In Yosemite and Monterey:

1. Open your Systems Preferences
2. Open Accessibility
3. Check the "Reduce transparency" option

Faster way:

1. Spotlight, type: pref
2. Search: transparency
3. Check the "Reduce transparency" option